Is there a way to improve an image with poor quality?
I have an image in a poor quality. Is there a service that can improve it? Or other ways, maybe?
Sharing a part of it. Tried to achieve improved quality online, but the texts look bad.
Thanks in advance

some of the parts aren't readable even to a human eye, what sort of magic improvements are you expecting to get..? I believe it should be remade from scratch

Thanks for your answer. If it was possible to remake it from scratch, I wouldn’t have asked the question. This wasn’t created in photoshop/illustrator nor by me and I have to send the source file. And yes, I am expecting to get the most magical magic, and asking whether it’s possible or not. From what I understood according to your reply, it is not. Thanks.

why would it not be possible to recreate this?

Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem is not recreating this in Illustrator, but the journal's requirements. I have to submit an original file(quality improvement is allowed), which has been made in the Ligplus program. To recreate this you have to own some files(in pdb program), and I don't have the contacts of the researcher who worked on this previously.

@VHR If that's the case, then we can't help here.  The image you have is beyond repair, I'm voting to close this as it's not within the scope of graphic design if recreating it is not an option.

@BillyKerr Isn’t asking for possible ways to improve image quality within the scope of graphic design? In my mind it is, so correct me if it’s not.
If it’s 100% impossible to do anything with the photo, then it’s another topic and yeah I am voting to close myself.

@VHR - sure, but it's not possible with this image. It's beyond repair, it's too low resolution, and some of the figures aren't even readable, and you don't want to recreate it. So, you've essentially ruled out the only feasible option.

From a graphics design point of view you just recreate it. Ok, so i have a science degree and i dont understand how running a image through some automated, possibly AI system, is better than recreating it. I mean it can be equally impossible to repeat. Either redraw on top, try to find original researcher or redo the work. Essentially you need to contact original author anyway at publish so...

That sample image is too far gone for any great improvement. Once any type in an image just looks "blurry" there's not a lot one can be done to bring back quality.
Trying to "sharpen" such text just makes it look "chunky" rather than blurry. .....

So, this results in a low quality image, simply a different form of "low quality". Type is still pretty bad, just bad in a different way. The only way to improves it, especially the type is to re-key things. But, even such unsatisfactory repairs would be "creating a new image" if one wanted to save the repairs. Which comments indicate is not acceptable. Something would have to give - either the only LIGPLUS mandate or the only improvements mandate. I have no idea if LIGPLUS even has any features capable of "merely improving" an image. It may simply be an image generator and not an editor.
If you want optimum quality, or even "acceptable" quality, it needs to be recreated.
The best method is to redraw it in a vector application - Inkscape or Illustrator. That way it's infinitely editable and scalable.
It's merely simple paths and circles. Not difficult for anyone who knows the tools. If you aren't familiar enough with the tools to recreate it, then hire someone. There are many "gig" websites where workers are available for this sort of thing. It should not take anyone more an an hour (max) to recreate.
This took me less than 10 minutes....


However, for this question....
The requirement that it "must the an image from LIGPLUS and only improvements are allowed." makes everything pretty much dead in the water, at least in the eyes of a designer. Designers won't have, or be familiar with, LIGPLUS. And if the image must be from LIGPLUS, then it's mandated that only LIGPLUS users could assist with this image. What is truly needed is an LIGPLUS user capable of recreating the image. No designer is going to be able to assist. Anything a designer does to the image, either trying to repair it or recreating it entirely, means they must save a new image.... which means it won't be an LIGPLUS image any longer.

Hey, thanks for your answer. This was created in the LIGPLUS program and they're asking for the original file as well, if there's no original file there's no point in recreating this, cause the journal won't accept it. Quality improvement is allowed. The researcher who created this doesn't work with me anymore and to generate this figure you have to own some original files. Otherwise of course it is a simple illustration.

Well then, not sure how a designer can assist you. Even if "quality improvement" are made, it will result in a new image and not simply the "original improved". I don't know how "the journal" could tell if it was from LIGPLUS initially or not. It sounds like the image needs to be recreated in LIGPLUS. Improving quality AND requiring it be an image created by LIGPLUS means.. you need to use LIGPLUS.. which "designers" won't have, much less be familiar with.

Essentially, you (or the "journal") have set up an impossibility where non-LIGPLUS users are concerned. It's absolutely not possible for a non-LIGPLUS user to improve an image without creating a new image.
